# TinyMCE Table Menu Not Showing

Tags: tinymce

I can't get the Table menu to show in TinyMCE.

From everything I've ready, the following config options should work:

```
var options = {
        selector: '#' + id,
        plugins: 'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak table code paste',
        toolbar_mode: 'floating',
        toolbar: 'bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | fontsizeselect | removeformat',
        forced_root_block: false,
        table_toolbar: 'tableprops tabledelete | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol',
        contextmenu: "link cut copy paste"
    };
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var options = {
        selector: '#' + id,
        plugins: 'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak table code paste',
        toolbar_mode: 'floating',
        toolbar: 'bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | fontsizeselect | removeformat | table',
        forced_root_block: false,
        table_toolbar: 'tableprops tabledelete | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol',
        contextmenu: "link cut copy paste"
    };
```